# Rails Associations - specific case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have a Post, Image and Video model and I need to model the associations between Post, Image and Video. Image and Video medium should belong to a Post. I also need the post record to be able to fetch all related post_media by calling @post.post_media.

I need these tests to pass:

```
context "viedos" do
  let(:post)  { create(:post) }
  let(:video) { create(:video) }

  it "can associate and video" do
    post.videos << video
    expect(post.videos.last).to eql(video)
  end

  it "can create an associated video" do
    video_attributes = attributes_for(:video)
    post.videos.create(video_attributes)
    expect(post.videos.last.attributes).to include(video_attributes.stringify_keys)
  end

  it "can create associated video as post_media" do
    post.post_media.create(medium: video)
    expect(post.videos.last).to eql(video)
  end
end 

context "post_media" do
  let(:post)  { create(:post) }
  let(:video) { create(:video) }
  let(:image) { create(:image) }

  before do
    post.videos << video
    post.images << image
  end

  it "should return all post related media" do
    expect(post.post_media.count).to eql(2)
    expect(post.post_media.map(&:medium)).to match_array([video, image])
  end
end
```

I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is looking very close, but not quite the same, as Single Table Inheritance, in which you define `Video` and `Image` as subtypes of `PostMedia`.

The interface is not quite the same, but seems close enough to investigate it as an option.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html